# Database Optimisation through denormalization and smaller rows

Tags: mysql, database

Does tables with many columns take more time than the tables with less columns during SELECT or UPDATE query? (row count is same and I will update/select same number of columns in both cases)

**example**: I have a database to store user details and to store their last active time-stamp. In my website, I only need to show active users and their names.

Say, one table named `userinfo` has the following columns: (`id,f_name,l_name,email,mobile,verified_status`). Is it a good idea to store last active time also in the same table? Or its better to make a separate table(say, `user_active`) to store the last activity timestamp?

The reason I am asking, If I make two tables, `userinfo` table will only be accessed during new signups(to INSERT new user row) and I will use `user_active` table (table with less columns) to UPADATE timestamp and SELECT active users frequently.

But the cost I have to pay for creating two tables is data duplication as `user_active` table columns will be (`id, f_name, timestamp`).

Comment: Any performance difference is likely to be immaterial.  Design for ease of use/maintenance first, optimising only when required. Remember Knuth's maxim: "*premature optimization is the root of all evil.*"

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is that, to a close approximation, having more columns in a table does not really take more time than having fewer columns for accessing a single row.  This may seem counter-intuitive, but you need to understand how data is stored in databases.

Rows of a table are stored on data pages.  The cost of a query is highly dependent on the number of pages that need to be read and written during the course of the query.  Parsing the row from the data page is usually not a significant performance issue.

Now, *wider* rows do have a very slight performance disadvantage, because more data would (presumably) be returned to the user.  This is a very minor consideration for rows that fit on a single page.

On a more complicated query, wider rows have a larger performance disadvantage, because more data pages need to be read and written for a given number of rows.  For a single row, though, one page is being read and written -- assuming you have an index to find that row (which seems very likely in this case).

As for the rest of your question.  The structure of your second table is not correct.  You would not (normally) include `fname` in two tables -- that is data redundancy and causes all sort of other problems.  There is a legitimate question whether you should store a table of *all* activity and use that table for the display purposes, but that is not the question you are asking.

Finally, for the data volumes you are talking about, having a few extra columns would make no noticeable difference on any reasonable transaction volume.  Use one table if you have one attribute per entity and no compelling reason to do otherwise.

Comment: I want to know more about "whether you should store a table of all activity and use that table for the display purposes". Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When returning and parsing a single row, the number of columns is unlikely to make a noticeable difference. However, searching and scanning tables with smaller rows is faster than tables with larger rows.

When searching using an index, MySQL utilizes a binary search so it would require significantly larger rows (and many rows) before any speed penalty is noticeable.

Scanning is a different matter. When scanning, it's reading through all of the data for all of the rows, so there's a 1-to-1 performance penalty for larger rows. Yet, with proper indexes, you shouldn't be doing much scanning.

However, in this case, keep the date together with the user info because they'll be queried together and there's a 1-to-1 relationship, and a table with larger rows is still going to be faster than a join.

Only denormalize for optimization when performance becomes an actual problem and you can't resolve it any other way (adding an index, improving hardware, etc.).